# Axios get request not accepting '[]' as param value

Tags: vuejs2, axios

We are migrating existing jQuery Ajax calls to Vue Axios. When we add any params which is having [] characters then request is failing to call back-end service and it is successful if we exclude the parameter which is having [] character.

Success request url which is existing **Ajax** URL in network tab:
http://localhost:8080/app_Server/FetchData?userId=alex&queryListStr=%5B%5D

Failure request url Which is **Axios** URL in network tab:
http://localhost:8080/app_Server/FetchData?userId=alex&queryListStr=[]

I can see that Ajax encoding [] characters but not in Axios.

I'm trying to pass parameters in the URL parameters in my GET request as follows

```
public async fetchRows(data:any){
        try {
            const url="http://localhost:8080/app_Server/FetchData";
            const resp = await axios.get(url, {  
                params: {                      
                  userId : "alex",                
                  querytr :"[]"                               
                }
            });        
            console.log(`this is the response: ${resp}`);            
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`);
          };        
    }
```

The parameter **queryStr** has characters **"[]"**. Same parameters are working if we pass those in jquery $.getJSON() API. Is it problem with encoding of parameters while making a request.Is Axios ignoring [] characters to encode.

Comment: your code works fine for me. here is my test https://repl.it/repls/FantasticVerticalAttribute 
https://beeceptor.com/console/testso

Comment: the test server is able to get the `[]` parameter

Comment: Can you review you question and edit it, please

Comment: May I know which appserver you are using it. I am using tomcat

Comment: I use mock online server https://beeceptor.com/ , as far as I can tell there is no issue with axios